# getting "reached maximum number of connections" error with large volume of http requests on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm attempting to do some stress testing on my GAE application
to see how it's performance holds up with a large number of
simultaneous users.  I tried having a 100 threads each send an https
requests within 1 second, but half of them failed with a 503 status code the following
message:
"Error: Connection not allowed: reached maximum number of
connections."

This is a paid app, so I tried upgrading the instance class and
setting up some idle instances, but it doesn't seem to make any
difference.

Is there a limit on the number of simultaneous connections?  Or is
this because all the requests are generated from the same host?

Thanks

EDIT: Response to Kyle: I'm using jmeter and sending 100 simultaneous requests to google.com doesn't ahve any issues.
Response to Nick: I'm not expecting individual clients to send lots of simultaneous requests, I was trying to simulate 100 users sending 1 request each.

Comment: Just to confirm that this is an issue with GAE and not your testing software. Are you able to connect all 100 threads to a non-appengine site, Google.com for example?

Comment: If you're trying to send 100 concurrent requests from a single machine, you're probably hitting a limit put in place to prevent abuse - not a fundamental limit of App Engine. Are you expecting clients to send 100 concurrent requests each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbeknownst to me, a colleague had added a custom throttling filter to our application :)  I removed this from the web.xml and it solves the problem.